# Why PyQt4 DialogBox OpenFileName freeze until other threads have finished under Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt4, pyqt4, freeze

**Under Linux**, the QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames() freeze in a script who have no other GUI until other process have done, even if it runs in a separate thread or Qthread.

I've tested under Ubuntu x64 14.04 to 16.04
(python 3.4.4/3.5.1 + libqt4-dev 4.8.6/4.8.7 + python3-pyqt4 4.9.1/4.11.4)

But surprisingly it **works as expected under Windows** 7, without freezing !
(python-3.4.4.amd64 + PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.7-x64)

```
import time
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread

class process(QThread):
    def __init__(self, files):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.files = files

    def run(self):
        print(self.files)

        # simulates a long process
        for i in range(10):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
files = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()

thread = process(files)
thread.start()
thread.wait()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce any problems on Linux. Exactly when is this "freeze" supposed to occur?

Comment: The DialogBox freeze after I click the open button or try to close the window. The freeze persists until the loop has print 10 times in the terminal. Please, describe your environment.

Comment: I'm testing on arch-linux,. I suspect the difference is that you get a native gtk dialog, whereas I get a kde one. Try using the `DontUseNativeDialog` option. Or try putting `app.processEvents()` after the `getOpenFileNames` line.

Comment: I've just tested the code on debian 8 (kde 4) and OpenSuse (kde 5) : it works but display non-blocking errors in the terminal (startkdeinitlock(1816) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-...). On the other hand, it works like a charme on kubuntu 15.10 without any error. Very strange...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested ekhumoro, the problem come from native DialogBox under a gtk desktop.

Add "options=QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog" to getOpenFileNames's args resolves completely the problem (no freeze or error message).